# How to convert a DataFrame that only has unique value in one column based on one column in specific value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like this way:

```
item_id    item_price 
1          10.0       
1          5.0        
1          6.0        
1          7.0        
2          2.0        
3          3.0        
4          5.0
```

And I try to get a DataFrame that `item_price` column only consists of a series of unique values. And drop other rows that don't fit this condition like this way:

```
 item_id    item_price         
 2          2.0        
 3          3.0        
 4          5.0
```

BUT, I am confused on how to implement it in Pandas. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with parameter `subset` for identify column for check duplicates and `keep=False` for remove all dupe rows:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['item_id'], keep=False)
print (df)
   item_id  item_price
4        2         2.0
5        3         3.0
6        4         5.0
```